# codeigniter: Posting to database

Tags: codeigniter, post, codeigniter-2

I need help to post a question to the database with the answers. But, I am having problems with testing. I would appreciate it someone could check everything is correct. I'm unsure if the post action in the form (View) is correct. The outcome for posting display 404 Page Not Found. I don't no if its the URL or server.

Comment: You are not calling any views in your add() method. if you are just testing you can echo out from inside the method -- but otherwise you need to call a view, optionally passing $data to it $this->load->view( 'form_question', $data );

Comment: could you help write the command to do this to solve my problem please.

Comment: you know that HTML supports input arrays? Maybe you could try using those instead, it will make your code look a lot better example of how to achieve this is use the name attribute of HTML as follow <input type="text" name="answer[]" /> It will now become an array in your post, play around a little and I'm sure you can find a nice clean way of implementing this.

Comment: Work through the tutorial in the codeigniter manual so you learn all the basics like how to load a view.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help

```
if($_POST){
        $question = $this->input->post('question_add');

        $answer1 = $this->input->post('answer_01');
        $answer2 = $this->input->post('answer_02');
        $answer3 = $this->input->post('answer_03');

        $answercorrect = $this->input->post('answer_correct');

         $this->quiz->addQuestion($question, $answer1, $answer2,  $answer3,     $answercorrect);
        redirect(base_url().'add');//redirect to your form
    }else{
    $this->load->view('form');//your view here 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this will work .

return 1 from your model addQuestion() at the last.

```
function addQuestion($question,$answer1, $answer2,  $answer3, $answercorrect) {

    //add questions
    $data = array (
        'quizid' => 5,
        'questions' => $question,
        'answerid' => '4'
    );

    $this->db->insert('questions', $data);

    //get id of questions

    $this->db->select('id');    
    $this->db->where('question', $question);    
    $idQuestion = $this->db->get('questions');  

    //add answer

    $data = array(
        'questionid' => $idQuestion->row()->id,
        'answer' => $answer1
    );

    $this->db->insert('answers',$data); 

  //add answer
    $data = array(
        'questionid' => $idQuestion->row()->id,
        'answer' => $answer2
    );

    $this->db->insert('answers',$data); 

    $data = array(
        'questionid' => $idQuestion->row()->id,
        'answer' => $answer3

    );

    $this->db->insert('answers',$data); 

    $data = array(
        'questionid' => $idQuestion->row()->id,
        'answer' => $answercorrect

    );

    $this->db->insert('answers',$data); 


    //get id of questions

    $this->db->select('id');    
    $this->db->where('answer', $answercorrect); 
    $idQuestion = $this->db->get('answers');    

    //update the question with the correct answer id

    $data = array(
        'answerid' => $question->row()->id

    );

    $this->db->where('question', $question);
    $this->db->update('questions', $data); 

    return 1;

 }
```

In controller

```
function add() {

    $question = $this->input->post('question_add');

    $answer1 = $this->input->post('answer_01');
    $answer2 = $this->input->post('answer_02');
    $answer3 = $this->input->post('answer_03');

    $answercorrect = $this->input->post('answer_correct');

    $query =$this->quiz->addQuestion($question, $answer1, $answer2,  $answer3, $answercorrect);

if($query==1)
{
 $this->load->view('form_question');  //where you want to redirect 
}

}
```